# CMake ошибка SW_DIR-NOTFOUND

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, g++

Я собираю библиотеку `teseract` из исходников через `CMake (cmake-gui)`.Компилю под `MinGW32`.
Во время компиляции появляется ошибка `SW_DIR-NOTFOUND`.

Как это исправить?
Или может есть другой способ что бы подключить `teseract` к проекту на `Qt c++`?

[image: SW_DIR-NOTFOUND]

Comment: Указать его надо

Comment: А где его найти?

Comment: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/2876

Comment: А где найти `sw` что бы выполнить `sw install`?

Comment: Вы читали документацию https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Compiling? Там прямым текстом написано *Download the latest SW (Software Network https://software-network.org/) client from https://software-network.org/client/.*

Comment: Я так понимаю, что **SW** -- это зависимость. Тебе её нужно установить и добавить в `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` путь к её родительскому каталогу (т.е. к каталогу, где будет лежать каталог **SW**)

Comment: Я сделал через `sw build`. Как мне теперь подключить `teseract` к моему проекту,используя `INCLUDEPATH +=...`  и `LIBS += ...`?